# Single SQL Query to validate input values

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have written a Stored procedure which has three argumets

```
@UserID1 BIGINT 
@UserID2 BIGINT 
@UserID3 BIGINT
```

What I want to achieve is to write a single SQL query against table **dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles** column ID so that @UserID1, @UserID2, @UserID3 are present in ID column of dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles.

For example, I have received three values in variables and I want to confirm they are part of Id column. i.e. ID column of table has values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and UserID1 is 2, UserID2 is 5 and UserID3 is 7. So it should give true else false.

I can implement using three different queries but I am not getting any clue to do it in a single query.

Comment: You want to insert 3 ids in one column of table ? or want to fetch record for all 3 ids ?

Comment: I have received three values in variables and I want to confirm they are part of Id column. i.e. ID column of table has values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and UserID1 is 2, UserID2 is 5 and UserID3 is 7. So it should give true else false.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
SELECT      CASE WHEN SUM( CASE
                WHEN @UserID1 = ID THEN 1
                WHEN @UserID2 = ID THEN 1
                WHEN @UserID3 = ID THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END ) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS [AllThree]
FROM        aspnet_UsersInRoles
```

*(untested code)*

...assuming that the ID column is unique. If all three IDs are in the table, then you should end up with a summed value of 3. This will allow you to process the table in a single pass, but you don't get the advantages of index lookups like you get in [Upendra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627524/211627).